# Asynchronous migration and opening - CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, core-data, core-data-migration

I am using CoreData and a FetchedResultsController. This works very well, However, I sometimes experience that the managedObjectContext is nil when the fetchedResultsController is initialized. This occurs more often during migrations so I am starting to believe Core Data is accessed before the migration is done (?).

If that is the case, it would be nice to know when the migration has completed before anything tries to access the data.

My question is, is there a way to asynchronously migrate the data?

I set up the Core Data Stack in the AppDelegate using this code (The managedObjectContext is passed to the initial view controller in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
lazy var containerURL: URL = {

    return FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.company.app")!

}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "databaseModel", withExtension: "momd")!

    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    var databaseStoreURL = self.containerURL.appendingPathComponent("Data.sqlite")

    let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : true]

    do {

        try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: "DataBaseStore", at: databaseStoreURL, options: options)

    } catch {

        coordinator = nil

        //Handle error

    }

    return coordinator

}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Comment: Can you share your code that sets up your Core Data stack? The migration will be asynchronous if it’s done on a background thread, but the actual method is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am only using lightweight migration. Code is added!